# ST_MAKEPOLYGON inverse function

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a function to inverse the ST_MAKEPOLYGON and get a linestring from a polygon?

The best option I have found so far is to modify the geometry at the WKB level.

```
with data AS (
  SELECT ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_MAKELINE([
    ST_GEOGPOINT(7.48,6.74),
    ST_GEOGPOINT(7.50,6.73),
    ST_GEOGPOINT(7.47,6.76),
    ST_GEOGPOINT(7.48,6.74)
  ])) AS my_polygon
    )
SELECT
  ST_GEOGFROMWKB(CONCAT(b'\x01\x02',SUBSTR(ST_ASBINARY(my_polygon),7)))
FROM data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT ST_EXTERIORRING(my_polygon)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]